# Object doesn't support property or method 'fnSettings'

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using DataTables version 1.7.2 and i have sample below initialization peace of code that.

```
var oTable;

function TableSorter(arr) {
    if (arr == 'audit') {
        oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            buttons: ['excel'],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
        });
    }
}
```

I then have a button column on the table which when clicked calls the function below.

```
 function ToggleSortEvent(mode) {
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
    var cols = oSettings.aoColumns;
    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
        cols[i].bSortable = mode;
    }
}
```

The line `var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();` is throwing the following javascript error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'fnSettings'

In chrome, ther error is

> Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnSettings is not a function

Comment: it might be an ignorant comment but.. isn't the function called settings() ? according to the docs.. https://datatables.net/reference/api/settings()

Comment: My understanding was that new the newer version (1.10) uses DataTable and the older versions use dataTable. http://www.datatables.net/new/1.10, and it seems like you can use the 2 initialisation types together to access a particular version's features..... If you use v 1.7.2 is impossible `$('#myTable').DataTable()` you should use `$('#myTable').dataTable()`